# Getting array values in php from jQuery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to send an array from jQuery post to PHP. 
But I am not getting any values with the below code. 
Could anyone help ?

**jQuery**

```
      $("body").on("click", ".js-form",function(event){

         var arr = [];
         i = 0;

          $('.addcolor').each(function() {

              if( $(this).text()=="done"){

              arr[i++]= $(this).data('request-id');
              }  

          });

          alert(arr);
          $.post("../ajax/save_Request.php", {requestids:arr, action:'save_request' })   

      });
```

**alert(arr)-> prints 11,24,35** (eg)

But I am not getting any values in the following PHP variable.

**PHP**

```
$ids = ( isset($_POST['requestids']) ) ? $_POST['requestids'] : 0;
```

Comment: Just do a `print_r($_POST);` in the PHP what does that show

Comment: So `print_r($_POST)` what do you see?

Comment: Hi, it is not displaying anything in the browser screen, I think because the php file is an internal logic page, not the interface page.

Comment: Can you monitor the Network tab while you send this request? Are you certain that's the path to your PHP file?

Comment: I don't see you echoing anything in your PHP code. How are you going to see it on screen or get it as a result?

Comment: i added echo. still no display.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `'choices[]'`

```
$.post( "test.php", { 'choices[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

See more in : [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and search the key "Pass arrays of data to the server". I think that you missed `[]`. Try it and return me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the array to a JSON string first, using

```
var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Now that it's a JSON string, you can simply pass it through a hidden field. Then, once you get the string back from the PHP page, you can turn it back into an array using

```
$array = json_decode($arr, true);
```

where $arr is the JSON string.

I had a similar problem with trying to pass an array from JQuery to another PHP page and this worked for me.